# How can I launch PuTTy in fullscreen from command line

Tags: putty, puppy-linux

I'm using Puppy Linux and am trying to launch PuTTy in fullscreen from the command line. Are there any parameters for this?

I am currenly doing

```
putty - load mysession
```

I am unable to choose a fullscreen option from PuTTy itself as the .pet file I used to install PuTTy is missing a few options, fullscreen included.

Comment: Is [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/359953/how-to-start-putty-in-a-maximized-window) what your looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can also ask the **xterm** emulator (in that case the putty) to enter in full screen mode, from the server-side, you could add at your .profile (or .bash_profile) script, something like:

```
printf '\e[9;1t'
```

Firstly, look at your putty settings if it's allowing itself to accept these escape sequences from de server.

And as you are in a profile script, you can also activate this mode using conditions, like for some users, and so on.